# Normal Distribution Z Scores!

Tags: normal-distribution

I have been stuck on this question for some time now.

A bone mineral density test is used to identify a bone disease. The result of a bone density test is commonly measured as a z score, and the population of the z scores is normally distributed with a mean of 0 and St Dev of 1. If the mean bone density test score is found for 9 randomly selected subjects, find the probability that the mean is greater than 0.50.

I have to say, I am completely lost. I've tried looking for the z-score for 0.5 and subtracting it from 1 but got the wrong answer.

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", "Please help", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: "Please help!" Again, how do you suggest that we do that?

Comment: Use $$\bar{z} = \frac{z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_9}{9},$$ compute the mean and standard deviation of $\bar{z}$, and ....

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am confused as to how to compute the z score for each of the subjects.